# checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError always return Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)"

Tags: ios, nsurl

I am trying to use: checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError of NSURL class

But I always get FALSE and the NSError shows : Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)"

I checked the URL with safary and it works, any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not the method you are looking for. The description of the method in NSURL's class reference states:

`Returns whether the resource pointed to by a file URL can be reached.`

The method should be used to test reachability of file URLs, you cannot check whether an internet resource is available or not using this method.

You'll find several answers in stack overflow if you search for reachability testing or something similar.. However, you could probably just attempt to reach the URL and handle the error if that fails.

Comment: Yes, I know, the url is: `http://server/myfile.ipa`, This url would be a valid url, or not?

Comment: File urls start with "file://" and they refer to files that can be reached from within your system. The url you're trying to reach requires that an http connection is made so that will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that it's the answer that I was looking for.

Thanks :)

And sorry for the delay.